# C++ ProgressBar and function (multithreading)

Tags: multithreading, visual-studio-2013, c++-cli, progress-bar

I have a program (C++ Form App, Viusal Studio 2013) that pressing a particular key on form launches the function that run about 20 seconds. I would like to set one progress bar that will indicate the state of the function. I know that the execution of the functions and UI have to put in different thred just do not know how to do it.. Can someone help?? Thanks!!

This is a function call:

```
private: System::Void BzapocniObradu_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) 
{
     ...
     String^ a = JPGtoPPM(picPath[i]);
     ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to include this namespace:

```
using namespace System::Drawing;
```

Then do something like that:

```
void PintarPictureBox(String^ strTexto,int ancho, PictureBox ^pictureBox1,Color Color1, Color Color2){
    using namespace System::Drawing::Drawing2D;

    Bitmap^ bmp = gcnew Bitmap(pictureBox1->Width, pictureBox1->Height);

    Graphics^ g = Graphics::FromImage(bmp);

    if(ancho <= 0)
        pictureBox1->Image = nullptr;

    else
    {
        Point point1 = Point(0,10);
        Point point2 = Point(ancho,10);
        LinearGradientBrush^ linGrBrush = gcnew LinearGradientBrush(
                    Point(0,10),
                    Point(ancho,10),
                    Color1, Color2);

        Pen^ pen = gcnew Pen(linGrBrush);

        g->FillRectangle(linGrBrush, 0, 0, ancho, pictureBox1->Height);
    }

    System::Drawing::Font^ drawFont = gcnew System::Drawing::Font( "Arial",8 );
    SolidBrush^ drawBrush = gcnew SolidBrush( Color::White );

    g->DrawString(strTexto,
        drawFont, drawBrush,
        0,0);

    pictureBox1->Image = bmp;

    delete g;
}
```

After that , to use it:

```
//in this case img_HP is my PictureBox and iHPCurrent/iHPMax are variables of stathook.
PintarPictureBox(iHPCurrent.ToString() + " / " + iHPMax.ToString(),(img_HP->Width*iHPCurrent)/iHPMax,
        img_HP,Color::FromArgb(150,0,0),Color::Red);
```

Source: https://ccplz.net/threads/tutorial-how-to-make-a-cute-progress-bar-cli-c.26895/

Off course this is just an example how to implement a progress bar, you can modify it to your needs.

I hope that support you question.

Comment: So you can use the following example:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12740/Threads-with-Windows-Forms-Controls-in-Managed-C